# prompt for an error when no argv is provided expect script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, expect

I have to run an expect script for ssh login purpose, but I need to create a file providing the argv while executing the command.

When I run this below script file is created.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set file [lindex $argv 0]
set date [exec date "%Y-%m-%d"]

spawn sh -c "touch output-$file-$date.csv"
```

**command output**

```
[root@centseven ~]# ./demo A
spawn sh -c touch output-A-2017-September-21.csv
[root@centseven ~]# ll output-
output--2017-September-21.csv   output-A-2017-September-21.csv
```

But with the argv the script works & the file is created, what I want is, if the argv is not provided while executing the script `./demo` then it should give error & the argv should be A or B nothing apart from that.

Is this possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere at the top add something like

```
if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
  puts stderr "Usage: $argv0 file"
  exit 1
}
```

See `llength(n)` for details on the list length procedure. For precisely only `A` or `B` as the single argument (a very strange limitation) `if` accepts `expr(n)` expressions so

```
if {[llength $argv] != 1} {
  puts stderr "Usage: $argv0 (A|B)"
  exit 1
}
set firstarg [lindex $argv 0]
if {!($firstarg eq "A" || $firstarg eq "B")} {
  puts stderr "Usage: $argv0 (A|B)"
  exit 1
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to have only `A` or `B` as a $argv.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call out to `date`: expect actually has 2 builtin commands for this:

1. the [`clock`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm) command from Tcl

   ```
   set date [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%d-%B-%Y"]
   ```
2. or the expect `timestamp` command

   ```
   set date [timestamp -format "%d-%B-%Y"]
   ```

I would strongly encourage you to use a different date format: `%Y-%m-%d` -- that's the ISO8601 standard. It is unambiguous. And it sorts the same lexically and chronologically.

Comment: Thanks for adding `ISO8601` to my notice, I have implemented it.